# How to add error handling to an async function call?

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

Currently the typescript code has this:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (prepAttrsRef.current) {
      prepAttrsRef.current.addEventListener('documentstatechanged', 
      async (evt: CustomEvent<FlowDocumentState>) => {
        if (evt.detail.draftState === 'all-changes-published') {
          dispatch(updateIsFlowpublished(true));
          let cleanSteps: readonly CleanStep[] = [];
          if (prepAttrsRef.current) {
            cleanSteps = await prepAttrsRef.current.getAllStepsOfTypeAsync('clean');
            if (cleanSteps && cleanSteps.length > 0 && cleanSteps[0] !== undefined) {
              await cleanSteps[0].selectAsync();
            }
          }
        }
      });
    }
    return () => {
      //TBC: cleanup
    };
  }, []);
```

Now we know that `selectAsync()` method returns a promise:

```
selectAsync(): Promise<SelectResponse>
```

And the `SelectResponse` could contain error message:

```
SelectResponse: { success: true } | { errorMessage: string; errorType: SelectError; success: false }
```

So in this case, how to add error handling code to `await cleanSteps[0].selectAsync();` ? Should the `await` keyword to be removed here?

Comment: No, don't remove `await` if you're dealing with a promise. Do add a  `try`/`catch` block though

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. So I can use try/catch even the  `selectAsync()` method doesn't throw exception?

Answer (score 0):

So basically selectAsync method handles errors (those that are throw as and Error) and returns response object depending on success or failure.

You can get that response by

```
const response = await cleanSteps[0].selectAsync();
```

And check

```
const response = await cleanSteps[0].selectAsync();
if (response.success) {
   // Do some success handling
} else {
  // Do some error handling, you have { errorMessage: string; errorType: SelectError; success: false } object here
}
```

It really depends on what you want to do in each scenario.

If you want to know how to handle async function errors in general then you need to wrap content that might throw an error with try catch block

```
prepAttrsRef.current.addEventListener(
  'documentstatechanged',
  async (evt: CustomEvent<FlowDocumentState>) => {
    try {
      if (evt.detail.draftState === 'all-changes-published') {
        dispatch(updateIsFlowpublished(true));
        let cleanSteps: readonly CleanStep[] = [];
        if (prepAttrsRef.current) {
          cleanSteps = await prepAttrsRef.current.getAllStepsOfTypeAsync(
            'clean'
          );
          if (
            cleanSteps &&
            cleanSteps.length > 0 &&
            cleanSteps[0] !== undefined
          ) {
            await cleanSteps[0].selectAsync();
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Do some error handling
    }
  }
);
```

[Promise chain in async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#rewriting_a_promise_chain_with_an_async_function)

Comment: Thanks! But can I use try/catch even the `selectAsync()` method doesn't throw exception? Moreover, why not do the try block only enclose the `selectAsync()` method instead of enclosing all the other lines?

Comment: If you are guaranteed that it won't throw an exception then there is no need to wrap it in try catch block. Also you are correct regarding enclosing part, there is no need to enclose all the lines in try block, only those with potential to throw exception. If you selectAsync methods doesn't throw exception, there is no need to enclose it. As mentioned before there are some libraries that do exception handling for you when fetching (SWR for React) and instead return data or error object.